# Why must I declare a type annotation in a class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The Code A works well, I think both Code B and Code C will work well too, but I failed, why?

In Code B and Code C, I think that the system can deduce the type of mDBHandle

**Code A**

```
class LogHandler(val mDBHandle:DBLogHandler=DBLogHandler()) {
}
class DBLogHandler() {
}
```

**Code B**

```
class LogHandler(val mDBHandle=DBLogHandler()) {
}
class DBLogHandler() {
}
```

**Code C**

```
class LogHandler(val mDBHandle:DBLogHandler()) {
}
class DBLogHandler() {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the [reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html):

> Function parameters are defined using Pascal notation, i.e. name: type. Parameters are separated using commas. **Each parameter must be explicitly typed**

This also applies to constructors.

Let's look at your examples:

```
class LogHandler(val mDBHandle:DBLogHandler=DBLogHandler())
```

Here you declare a read-only property of type `DBLogHandler` and a default value of a new instance (`DBLogHandler()`).

```
class LogHandler(val mDBHandle=DBLogHandler())
```

In this one the parameter (property) type declaration has been omitted, so it's incorrect.

```
class LogHandler(val mDBHandle:DBLogHandler())
```

Here it looks like the parameter type has been declared as `DBLogHandler()`, because the parentheses imply a function (or constructor) call. Therefore, it's not a valid declaration.

If you'd like to declare the `mDBHandle` property without a default value, you can do it like this:

```
class LogHandler(val mDBHandle:DBLogHandler)
```